# Correctness of bft resulting in shortest path

Tags: algorithms, shortest-path, correctness-proof, breadth-first-search, tree-traversal

I found the following proof concerning the correctness of a breadth-first traversal resulting in shortest path:
[image]

source: [https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~daw/teaching/cs170-s03/Notes/lecture6.pdf](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Edaw/teaching/cs170-s03/Notes/lecture6.pdf)

The key is that if we assume that we have a shorter path, we get a contradicition. I however do not fully understand with what the consequence of having a shorter path contradicts. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to indicate where you saw that.  We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  I've shared this feedback before [1](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/152549/proof-that-function-is-non-computable#comment320867_152549).

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: What's a bft?  Please define all terms in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contradiction is that we're assuming **the first time we've seen $w$** is through the node we're expanding, $v$.  However, if there were a shorter path, then the second-to-last node in that path must be some other node, $v'$.  Since the path is shorter, $dist[v'] < dist[v]$. But if that's the case then $v'$ should've been expanded prior to $v$, and **we would've seen $w$** when that happened, contradicting our assumption.